# What is the simplest persistent storage in Ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I have a very trivial Ionic v1 app that needs to store a persistent single string. What are my options, local file, sql? I have tried local storage and it is too unstable, I loose what is stored if the app is force quit.

I am currently using the [Ionic Settings](https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionic-settings) plugin with the [app settings](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences) plugin, but have not had very good results retaining the stored value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html) will help you decide which storage to use.

you have these options

- LocalStorage
- WebSQL
- IndexedDB

if you want to store just a string you should use localStorage it is simple and easy.

```
//set item
window.localStorage['key'] = "value";
//get Item
var value = window.localStorage['key'];
```

explore more storeage options and its advantages [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html).

Comment: My problem is the persistence of all three options. I need to store a string that will remain persistent even if the application is force quit.

Comment: all three provides persistence storage. data will not be lost even if user force closes the app. data will only be erased if user manually clears the app data.

Comment: localstorage will be reclaimed by the OS if the device starts running out of space. I used sqlite for v1 and still do for v3. I use pouchdb or ionic storage as middle tier to let me save json objects.